# How to set a specifc name in front of the name if it matches some certain condition in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets .

**sheet-1** contains names in column A like

1) Max

2) Sam

3) Ram

**sheet-2** also contains the name in column A but with some specific indicators in column B LIKE

COL"A" -   1) Max     , 2) Sam, 3) Ram

COL"B"  -    1       ,   2,    1

so as you can see in **sheet-2**  i have " 1" in COL"B" in  front of  Max and Ram in COL"A"

using this i want to mark values in front of names in **sheet-1**

eg-

in sheet-2 if  i have " 1" in COL"B" in  front of  Max and Ram in COL"A"  then mark Max and Ram in **sheet-1** COL"B" as "topper" and if it is 2 in case of Sam in **sheet-2** mark it as average in **sheet-1** COL "B" in front of Sam

is there any specific formula to do that ? i have searched but was unable to find it. it will be really helpful as i am new to this excel formulas and vba

Comment: Will sheet 2 have more than one entry for each of the people in worksheet 1?  If, so are you trying to sum up the values in worksheet 2?  What are the criteria for "topper"?  Examples of the data in the two sheets would help.

Comment: i have sheet-2  in which coL "a" contains names like 1) Max , 2) Sam, 3) Ram  & corresponding cOl "b" contains numbers 1,2,1    means in front of Max value -1, sam -2 and Ram-1..................so  in sheet-1 i have only names in col "a" like 1) Max , 2) Sam, 3) Ram     in same format so whatever names are having 1 in front of them in sheet2  i want to write topper in sheet-1 in front of those  names In col"b"  @Johny D

Comment: @Johnny D i have mentioned it above is their any way

Comment: Did the second edit make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following in B1 in sheet 1 and drag down:

```
 =IFERROR(CHOOSE(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$3,2,FALSE),"Topper","Average"),"")
```

If there were more names in lookup range extend this, `Sheet2!$A$1:$B$3`, to include all the additional rows.

`CHOOSE` function will return the item at the specified index, so if the lookup returns 1, it will return the first item in the following list i.e. `"Topper"`. It 2 then `"Average"`. If there was a third item it would go after `"Average"` etc.

The whole thing is wrapped in an `IFERROR` in case no matching value is found, in which case the empty string literal `""` is returned; though you could specify a different return message by placing your chosen text between the `"Text"`.

Sheet 1 formulas:

[image: Sheet 1 formulas]

Version 2 (in sheet 1 B2 drag down):

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$3,2,FALSE)=1,"Topper",IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$3,2,FALSE)>4,"Weak","Average")),"")
```

Comment: but just suppose if i have a lot of data with lots of names now i want to mark 1 as topper ,   2-4 as average and greater than 4 as weak now what should i do?? any help or idea is appreciable. @QHarr

Comment: like max -1 , ram-1,   sam-2, jam-3, ian-4   and cella-5, gen-6 etc. IN SHEET-2.   so i have to mark max, ram as topper  & sam, jam , ian as average  and cella, gen as weak in sheet-1 column "A" @QHarr

Comment: thanks alot @QHarr , however i have written  a code which is working fine as well will post it below

Answer (score 0):

below is the vba code for my above question and it is working great.

```
 Sub aa()
    Set Excel1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Excel2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim Excel1LR: Excel1LR = Excel1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    Dim Excel2LR: Excel2LR = Excel2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count


    For i = 2 To Excel1LR
    Dim Value1: Value1 = Excel1.Range("A" & i).Value

     For j = 2 To Excel2LR
     Dim Value2: Value2 = Excel2.Range("A" & j).Value

     If Value1 = Value2 Then
     Dim Value3: Value3 = Excel2.Range("B" & j).Value

     If Value3 = 1 Then
     Excel1.Range("B" & i).Value = "topper"

     ElseIf Value3 >= 2 And Value3 <= 4 Then
      Excel1.Range("B" & i).Value = "average"
Else
      Excel1.Range("B" & i).Value = "weak"
     End If

     Else


     End If
     Next
     Next

    msgbox "done"

    End Sub
```